# No image shown after inserting image using Blogdown Addins 'insert image' and remind me to download the image everytime I refresh the page

Tags: r, blogdown

I tried to insert image following the [tutorial](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rstudio-ide.html), but it doesnt work out. I insert image in the pop-up window from Addins 'Insert Image', it does copy the image to `content/post/2023-02-03-new-post/images` rather than `static/post/...`. I dont know whether I made a mistake or not. I have checked out my version of blogdown. and this problem happened to `.Rmd` file. I dont know why every time I refresh this page, IDM will be triggered to download the image.

```
> packageVersion('blogdown')
[1] ‘1.16’
```

[image: no image shown]

i hope to know how to make the image shown in the page

Comment: I found that inserting oneline image works well, but insert local image doesn't work well. no matter where the local image is saved, and I try both relative path or absolute path from root directory, they don't work well

Comment: `![this is a test image](static/post/2023-02-03-new-post/images/LenaRGB.tif)` doesnt work well

Comment: `![this is a test image](images/LenaRGB.tif)` also doesn't work well, and I find that there's a rule in Addins' insert image: `Warning: The target file path must be under the directory 'content/post/2023-02-03-new-post'.`

Comment: seems like this problem is nothing to do with theme, i try to insert local image in 2 themes, dont work well